# Manage Package upgrade failure - couldn't retrieve the design time component information for component X

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, validation, sandbox, developer-console

- I released a Managed Package version 1.1 and installed on both Developer Org **D1** and Sandbox Org **S1**.
- Later I added a new Lightning Component and Lightning Record Page to the Package and released a Major version 1.2.
- I am able to upgrade **D1** to 1.2 (and many other developer orgs).
- But when I tried upgrading **S1** from 1.1 to 1.2 it throwed me an error as below and installation failed:

> (Customer_Object_Record_Page) Validation Errors While Saving
>   Record(s), Details: There were custom validation error(s) encountered
>   while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error
>   encountered was "We couldn't retrieve the design time component
>   information for component nmspc:AnotherLightningPage.".

I am not able to understand the message `"We couldn't retrieve the design time component information for component X"` and what is so different from Developer Org to Sandbox Org.

*Note: All Lightning pages have access="global"*

Comment: My guess is that your Sandbox is on Summer '17. It may be a bug...

Comment: @sfdcfox exactly, it is on Summer '17 and it is our customer's Org. Is there any work around for this ?

Comment: Log a case with partner support. It's not something we can likely assist you with.

Comment: @sfdcfox Just an update, I signed up for a Summer 17 preview release and tried installing there. Installation went smooth without the above error. Can there be any specific deployment validations configured per org ?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen this error, and I don't have a way to easily replicate it. I was hoping it'd be something simple. Still, I hope you get an answer to this, it'd be great to know what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is accepted as known issue by Salesforce and patch fix is scheduled for all the instances as listed [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008jMrQAI). As mentioned by sfdcfox the issue is specific to Summer 17 (Sandbox Org) and not happening on Spring 17 (Developer Org).

Comment: We had the same issue in Spring '17 already - and id be interested to know if the fix needs to be applied to the target org or to the packaging org. Not all orgs have the fixed rolled out so far.

Comment: Also, we noticed that installation via upgrade API works whereas installation via UI fails with the error above

Comment: We still see this issue intermittently with certain orgs - what can we do?

Answer (score 5):

If anyone else gets later on 2019+ it could also indicate that the page that calls a component is not in the target org. The fix is to just add that to your package.

Just ran into that today.

Comment: `Just ran into that today` - yup. refactoring my sfdx-project into multiple sub-layers and needed to move my `lwc` folder from it's old place into a different layer

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me that I inserted LWC metadata in AURA metadata on package to deploy and this error was throw. Ex:

This is how I write:

`<types> <members>MyLWC</members> <name>AuraDefinitionBundle></name> </types>`

This was the correction:

`<types> <members>MyLWC</members> <name>LightningComponentBundle></name> </types>`