# Error While installing Beta-managed Bolt Solution Package

Tags: managed-package, beta-managed-package, lightning-bolt

I am facing this error while trying to install beta-managed package to my Dev Org (Platform version - Summer'17). I googled before posting the question, and found this link: [Question link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173449/manage-package-upgrade-failure-couldnt-retrieve-the-design-time-component-inf). However, as per this, already all patches are pushed to all Salesforce Orgs. So this should not be the cause.... But still I am facing this issue.

Error is : "We couldn't retrieve the design time component information for component X". Can anyone help on this?

[image]

Comment: Is your org on the winter 18 preview? If so then same issue

Comment: Not yet. We are trying to install in Partner Developer edition, and all Prod/Dev edition which are yet to be upgraded to Winter 18.

Comment: What is the component in question? Does the package successfully install in any other orgs?

Comment: @DanielBallinger,  It is design sub-component within Bolt Community Page.
Also, If i edit it in xml (using ecilpse or other tool) and remove this design component, I am able to deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

We are having similar issues outside Bolt but with Packages containing lightning components on RecordPages.

The issue was reported once already and was marked fixed by Salesforce some time ago.

We managed to have it reopened recently since we are still having those  issues in some (not all)) Orgs:

- Known Issue -  [Package installation/upgrade fails with: "We couldn't retrieve the design time component information for component"](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EGKsQAO)

Comment: Ok, got it.  Let me know, if you find any resolution for this.

We have also raised a Salesforce case. Lets c.